# Material UI - How do I align title, image and description in each row?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to align the title, image and description of each card within a row in my React app. This is how it is currently displayed:

[image]

Each child within the card in not aligned properly. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-hopper-035sl1?file=/src/App.js) is the link to my code.

Below is how I want it to display:

[image]

How can I align the contents of each card?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated question if you only need to center the header, remove the shadow of the card and make the spacing smaller you just need to add those to your code:

- In the parent `Grid`, `<Grid container spacing={1}>`
- Your `<Card style={{ height: "100%" }} elevation={0}>`
- Your `<CardHeader title={product.title} align="center" />` to align the title

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-kirch-0t5ksl?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Hi. I have updated my question with respect to how I want it to display.

Comment: Hi @Meeth i have updated my answer with the codesandbox. Of you need more changes please be very specific of what you need or what problem you are dealing with. Thanks

Comment: I've clarified my question further by updating the images. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: An easy solution would be to have a specific height for each element, like the header, the description, the image. Or else you should rethink of how you use the Grid  but would be a more complex solution specially when it will need to be responsive